# How to make a website with user registration and individual accounts?

Tags: web, server, cloud, profile

For a bit more context. I have an idea for a project. It's basically remote storage. People go on my website, they register for free, which creates a unique account for them, and there they can store files.

For a bit of clarification, I am relatively new to programming. I have made websites and a few Python games but nothing beyond that. The purpose of this project is essentially to have fun and learn something new.

From what I understand, I will need;

- A server to host all the user information
- A website with a decent user interface where users can register and manage their files.

What server host? what tools? All of that, no idea. I am not looking for someone to just tell me everything I need to know but I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
                                        .
```

Answer (score 0):

there !

**First, you have to choose what tech stack you are going to utilize.**

You said, you had ever used Python, you can choose it.
Actually, there are many Python frameworks Django and Flask.
I recommend you to use Flask because you are a new learner and it's easier to learn than Django.
This framework is for Backend development.
Since you are a new learner, I recommend you use sample built already perfectly for file uploading and focus on AJAX communication mainly.(If you can't find, I can send mine to you.)

Of course, how to do is totally up to you, so if you still want to learn something new building frontend yourself, you should choose HTML, CSS and JavaScript because they are the basics of web development.

**Second, you can start development based on tech stacks you chose.**

Sign in/Sign up functionality can be implemented easily since there are many resources but you have to keep the principle of security.
You can reference from https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/security-design-security-principles-and-threat-modeling.

After you build them, you will have to implement the file uploading functionality.
You can reference on https://pythonbasics.org/flask-upload-file/.
If you still don't see clearly, I can assist you from 18:00 to 19:00[JST].
But note that the importance is trying the best.

**Third, you will deploy using AWS EC2 or something like that.**

I hope my response is helpful to you.